# While scrolling using up/down arrow in JComboBox, It shouldn't update the top tile which shows selected item

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I want my combobox top tile only get updated when we hit enter key, not while scrolling using up/down arrows..

Currently when I scroll using up/down arrow, the current item which is currently highlighted is getting updated in top tile of `JComboBox` as selected item. I need to avoid this.

Here is my code. Thanks in advance!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingControlDemo {
    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JLabel headerLabel;
    private JLabel statusLabel;
    private JPanel controlPanel;

    public SwingControlDemo() {
        prepareGUI();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingControlDemo swingControlDemo = new SwingControlDemo();
        swingControlDemo.showComboboxDemo();
    }

    private void prepareGUI() {
        mainFrame = new JFrame("Java Swing Examples");
        mainFrame.setSize(400, 400);
        mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
        mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        headerLabel = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
        statusLabel = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);

        statusLabel.setSize(350, 100);

        controlPanel = new JPanel();
        controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        mainFrame.add(headerLabel);
        mainFrame.add(controlPanel);
        mainFrame.add(statusLabel);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void showComboboxDemo() {
        headerLabel.setText("Control in action: JComboBox");

        final DefaultComboBoxModel fruitsName = new DefaultComboBoxModel();

        fruitsName.addElement("Apple");
        fruitsName.addElement("Grapes");
        fruitsName.addElement("Mango");
        fruitsName.addElement("Peer");
        fruitsName.addElement("java");
        fruitsName.addElement("Mango");

        final JComboBox fruitCombo = new JComboBox(fruitsName);
        fruitCombo.setSelectedIndex(0);

        JScrollPane fruitListScrollPane = new JScrollPane(fruitCombo);

        JButton showButton = new JButton("Show");

        fruitCombo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (arg0.getModifiers() == ActionEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK || arg0.getModifiers() == ActionEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK || true) {
                    System.out.println("arg0" + "  " + arg0.getModifiers());
                }
            }
        });

        fruitCombo.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                    System.out.println("enter key pressed" + arg0.getKeyCode());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        System.out.println(fruitCombo.getComponentListeners().toString());
        controlPanel.add(fruitListScrollPane);
        controlPanel.add(showButton);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: `mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` instead of `mainFrame.addWindowListener( ....`.

Comment: Side note 2: `X || true` always evaluates as `true` for any boolean expression `X`. Remove the `|| true` in the `actionPerformed` implementation in `fruitCombo.addActionListener`.

Comment: I ve added it on purpose to check certain values we get on modifier when we do actions using mouse..

Comment: Side note 3: Construct and manipulate Swing GUI objects _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle Java has fixed this issue as it is not in par with selection using mouse.
But to enable the fix, we have to change default SWING UI property with key "ComboBox.noActionOnKeyNavigation". In the fix implemented in SourceCode they are using this property as flag. If we make it as true, JComboBox selection using keyboard wont trigger Action event. 
This link will give you details of the fix. This is from OpenJDK but i have confirmed in Oracle JDK 1.8.111
http://osdir.com/ml/swing-dev-java-openjdk/2013-01/msg00029.html

So Basically we have to add this lane

UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("ComboBox.noActionOnKeyNavigation",    true);

Comment: This does fix the issue. A separate but related issue is that once you select the item by pressing "Enter" key, the focus does not remain on the combo box. Did you experience this issue too?

Answer (score 2):

There is a property you can set on the combo box to prevent the firing of events when the arrow keys are used:

```
comboBox.putClientProperty("JComboBox.isTableCellEditor", Boolean.TRUE);
```

Note: you may (or may not) need to manually close the popup when using the above property:

```
/*
    This works on non editable combo boxes
*/
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class ComboBoxAction extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    public ComboBoxAction()
    {
        JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>();
        comboBox.addActionListener( this );

        comboBox.addItem( "Item 1" );
        comboBox.addItem( "Item 2" );
        comboBox.addItem( "Item 3" );
        comboBox.addItem( "Item 4" );

        //  This prevents action events from being fired when the
        //  up/down arrow keys are used on the dropdown menu

        comboBox.putClientProperty("JComboBox.isTableCellEditor", Boolean.TRUE);

        getContentPane().add( comboBox );
        getContentPane().add( new JTextField(), BorderLayout.SOUTH );
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println( e.getModifiers() );

        JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
        System.out.println( comboBox.getSelectedItem() );

        //  make sure popup is closed when 'isTableCellEditor' is used

//      comboBox.hidePopup();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ComboBoxAction frame = new ComboBoxAction();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
     }
}
```

Comment: I am not in favor of using this solution. I have tried this, But it changed JcomboBox button looks. Do you have any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

I have found one solution using custom keybinding actions. Here is the code with those changes.

```
package abcd;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup;

public class SwingControlDemo {

   private JFrame mainFrame;
   private JLabel headerLabel;
   private JLabel statusLabel;
   private JPanel controlPanel;

   public SwingControlDemo(){
      prepareGUI();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
      SwingControlDemo  swingControlDemo = new SwingControlDemo();      
      swingControlDemo.showComboboxDemo();
   }

   private void prepareGUI(){
      mainFrame = new JFrame("Java Swing Examples");
      mainFrame.setSize(400,400);
      mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
      mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
         public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent){
            System.exit(0);
         }        
      });    
      headerLabel = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);        
      statusLabel = new JLabel("",JLabel.CENTER);    

      statusLabel.setSize(350,100);

      controlPanel = new JPanel();
      controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

      mainFrame.add(headerLabel);
      mainFrame.add(controlPanel);
      mainFrame.add(statusLabel);
      mainFrame.setVisible(true);  
   }

   private void showComboboxDemo(){                                    
      headerLabel.setText("Control in action: JComboBox"); 

      final DefaultComboBoxModel fruitsName = new DefaultComboBoxModel();

      fruitsName.addElement("Apple");
      fruitsName.addElement("Grapes");
      fruitsName.addElement("Mango");
      fruitsName.addElement("Peer");
      fruitsName.addElement("java");
      fruitsName.addElement("mkm");

      final JComboBox fruitCombo = new JComboBox(fruitsName);
      fruitCombo.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN"), "cDownArrow");
      fruitCombo.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"), "cUpArrow");
      Action customDownArrow = new AbstractAction() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("in");
            JComboBox box = (JComboBox)arg0.getSource();
            BasicComboPopup pop = (BasicComboPopup)box.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleChild(0);
            JList list  = pop.getList();
            System.out.println("next index" + "  "+ (list.getSelectedIndex()+1)%box.getItemCount());
            list.setSelectedIndex((list.getSelectedIndex()+1)%box.getItemCount());

        }
    };

    Action customUpArrow = new AbstractAction() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            JComboBox box = (JComboBox)arg0.getSource();
            BasicComboPopup pop = (BasicComboPopup)box.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleChild(0);
            JList list  = pop.getList();
            System.out.println("next index" + "  "+ (list.getSelectedIndex()+1)%box.getItemCount());
            list.setSelectedIndex(((list.getSelectedIndex()-1)%box.getItemCount()+box.getItemCount())%box.getItemCount());
        }
    };
      fruitCombo.getActionMap().put("cDownArrow",customDownArrow);
      fruitCombo.getActionMap().put("cUpArrow", customUpArrow);
      fruitCombo.setSelectedIndex(0);

      JScrollPane fruitListScrollPane = new JScrollPane(fruitCombo);    

      JButton showButton = new JButton("Show");



      fruitCombo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if(arg0.getModifiers()==ActionEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK || arg0.getModifiers()==ActionEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK||true){
                System.out.println("arg0"+"  "+arg0.getModifiers());
            }


        }
    });

      /*fruitCombo.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(arg0.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                System.out.println("enter key pressed"+arg0.getKeyCode());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });*/
      System.out.println(fruitCombo.getComponentListeners().toString());
      controlPanel.add(fruitListScrollPane);          
      controlPanel.add(showButton);    
      mainFrame.setVisible(true);             
   }
}
```

Comment: This answer is not proper. We are selecting items in list element. I believe that scrollBar on JComboBox moves according to selection in JcombBox not according to selection in list. So if we do like it is mentioned in this answer, the scrollbar wont move according to your selection.